# Can't Inject dependency for List<t> as constructor argument using Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm using Unity to instantiate my MenuRepository instance. I'm getting the following error when trying to do so..

> The type list`1 has multiple constructors of length 1. unable to disambiguate.

I've tried the following registration, but with no luck..

```
container.RegisterType<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>(
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMonopolyEntitiesDbContext), 
    typeof(List<MenuLink>)));
```

**Here's my registration**

```
container.RegisterType<MenuLink>();
container.RegisterType <List<MenuLink>>();
container.RegisterType<IMonopolyEntitiesDbContext, MonopolyEntities>(
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>(
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), 
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMonopolyEntitiesDbContext), typeof(List<MenuLink>)));
```

**MenuRepository**

```
public class MenuRepository : IMenuRepository
{
    IMonopolyEntitiesDbContext _dbContext;
    List<MenuLink> _allsubMenus;

    public MenuRepository(IMonopolyEntitiesDbContext context, List<MenuLink> allsubMenus)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
        _allsubMenus = allsubMenus;
    }
}
```

Comment: List has multiple constructors. Unity can’t find out which should get used…you need to provide more information to unity. 
But I would recommend you creating a service which creates the list and inject this service into your repository.

Comment: Exactly so, Unity needs to know whether you mean `List<T>(sequence)` or `List<T>(length)`.

Comment: What does `List<MenuLink>` contain? Is this a fixed list of `MenuItem` objects that doesn't change for the duration of the application? Or is this data that is requeried from the database on each request? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hi ray abu, I've written a quite lengthy answer for you. I haven't posted it yet though, because I'm missing a some essential information to be able to answer this question. If you can answer my previous question about `List<MenuLink>`, it allows me to post my answer and help you with your problem.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. List<MenuItem>  menuItem object's state wouldn't change during the application and a singleton, but the collection can change. MenuItem object will hold data called from a datastore. I have resolve this issue now, will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 3):

I used InjectionConstructor with no parameters.

```
using (var c = new UnityContainer())
{
    c.RegisterType(typeof(List<string>), new InjectionConstructor());
    c.RegisterType<IMyParamClass, MyParamClass>();

    c.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>(
                    new PerThreadLifetimeManager(),
                    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IMyParamClass),
                    typeof(List<string>)));

    var obj = c.Resolve<IMyClass>();
    obj.write();
}
```

.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that the goal of an IoC container is to map abstractions to implementations and to build up object graphs from that. So to be able to create objects, Unity needs to know how to create objects. `List<T>` however, is not your typical service type. It has multiple constructors and Unity has therefore no clue of how to create this type.

But even if it did know how to create it (for instance by using the default constructor of `List<T>`), this still would be rather useless to you, because in that case an empty list would be injected into consumers. That's hardly ever useful, at all.

So the least you should do is exactly specify what to inject. For instance by doing this:

```
container.RegisterInstance<List<MenuLink>>(new List<MenuLink>
{
    new MenuLink { Id = 1, Name = "foo" },
    new MenuLink { Id = 2, Name = "bar" },
    new MenuLink { Id = 3, Name = "foobar" },
});
```

This will work for you, since you stated that the `List<MenuLink>` is practically a singleton and is not populated from the database. However, registering this `List<MenuLink>` in your container would still be problematic, because this `List<T>` can now be injected into any consumer, while you should never do this. This `List<MenuLink>` is an implementation detail of the `MenuRepository` that is probably responsible of updating it. Injecting the `List<MenuLink>` into other consumers is risky, because `List<T>` is not thread-safe. It's best to keep this `List<T>` internal to the `MenuRepository`, so it can do the proper locking.

So instead of registering the `List<MenuLink>` in the container, register the repository with the list explicitly as follows:

```
var menuLinks = new List<MenuLink>
{
    new MenuLink { Id = 1, Name = "foo" },
    new MenuLink { Id = 2, Name = "bar" },
    new MenuLink { Id = 3, Name = "foobar" },
};

container.RegisterType<IMenuRepository, MenuRepository>(
    new PerThreadLifetimeManager(), 
    new ParameterOverride("allsubMenus", menuLinks));
```